# Hausdroff property in metric space.

Tags: metric-spaces

I have seen the statements "Every convergent sequence is a cauchy sequence" 
& 
"Every Cauchy sequence in R is convergent" .
My question is that whether these statements means that a sequence is convergent if and only if it is convergent? The another statement for second statement is " R is complete metric space" . So what should i conclude ?

Comment: Note that in $\mathbb Q$, every convergent sequence is Cauchy, but not every Cuachy sequence converges. - (Albeit all this has little to do with Hausdorff)

Comment: Both directions means iff. And that all Cauchy sequences converge is a definition of completeness, right. And what has all this to do with the Hausdorff (not droff!) property?

Comment: Can you please make the title a relevant reflection of your question??

Comment: I am.extremly sorry for the wrong title. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily prove that if $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a convergent sequence in a metric space, then it is a Cauchy sequence; that result is true for *all* metric spaces. It is not true in all metric spaces that every Cauchy sequence is convergent: that is the defining property of *complete* metric spaces, and not all metric spaces are complete. $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, however, is complete, so it’s true that every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric is convergent.

Comment: @user5273591: You’re welcome.